# rsa public key exponent bytes length

Tags: rsa, public-key-encryption, csr, exponent

I'm trying to create a script that checks the RSA public key exponent bytes length of CSRs. I need to check if the exponent has 3 or 4 bytes. If I use OpenSSL, I'm not able to see the the true value of the exponent:

[image]

As you can see, the exponent is 65537 (0x10001). I cannot see if the real value is 00 01 00 01 (4 bytes) or 01 00 01 (3 bytes). If I check with ASN.1 Editor, I can see that the value is 00 01 00 01.

[image]

But I'm not able (at least that I know of) to automate this check in a script.

Comment: What is the data source? Maybe also the length is encoded in this "file"?

Comment: You need to write a program that parses the binary encoded ASN.1 format. Note that a properly DER encoded exponent will always have the shortest form, e.g. 65537 will always be encoded as 01 00 01. I think you are misreading the output of the ASN.1 editor.

Comment: the data source is .csr's.
Some .csr's may encode 65537 as 01 00 01 and others may encode 65537 with 00 01 00 01. With ASN.1 Editor, I can see the the diference, with asn1parse of openssl, I'll always see 01 00 01.